# Generate SSRS Reports for resolved cases by month for selected cusotmers

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an SSRS report that generates customer invoice for selected customers. I want to be able to generate this report each month for selected customers. What do I do to be able to generate a report for, say, April for ABC Corp.? I have the case 'created on' date.

Comment: Can't you just add date parameters that filter on the 'created on' date? If I want a report for April Invoices then I just filter the Dataset from 01/04/2013 to 30/04/2013?
Please elaborate more on what you have and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I create a 'Case' in CRM for a specific customers and log 'Activities' that I perform as part of the case. My report generates this information at the end of each month. Right now, it shows all cases that were ever created for that customer. I want my report to show only cases that were created in April for eg.

Answer (score 1):

Look up [Reporting Services Subscriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762.aspx).

Standard subscriptions allow you to set up the report server to send you a report for ABC Corp every month.  You enter the parameters (such as ABC Corp) the way you would enter them to generate the report manually.

Data Driven Subscriptions allow you to automatically distribute reports to people.  The parameters can be different for each person, and it doesn't look the same as the manual approach.  You may create stored procedures to manage data driven subscriptions, and these are going to be more complex than standard subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try with Subscriptions.